# Extract .class from EXE

Tags: java, exe, reverse, dump, dbg

I have an EXE file and I wanna look inner of classes. I don't want to make a work jar file I only need to look inner. The application was written with java and was packed with jar2exe. All information which I found directed me on this [article](http://reverseengineeringtips.blogspot.com/2014/12/unpacking-jar2exe-21-extracting-jar.html?m=1) Packed on level 3.

All the software is present, there is a general understanding, but I do not understand at what point I made a mistake.

I found value in Resource Hacker.
[Resource Hacker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmLp0.png)

Next it uses OllyDbg, but OllyDbg does not support x64 applications, so I use x64 dbg

He enters the Enter expression window from the OllyAdvanced plugin, but I didn't find such a plugin for x64 dbg, so I used the method from the 00:59 [Video](https://youtu.be/UaGAv1y7hY0). Got this value

[Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFt6V.png)

I go to dbg and run the software there. I go to the window with the hexadecimal value and enter the value. I'm setting a breakpoint.

[breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms2JI.png)

Run the program and get here

[Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Bkx.png)

The article goes on to describe a loop pass and a memory dump

What kind of loop and what to dump into memory, I do not understand. Maybe I made a mistake in the previous steps?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: @dan1st in Jar2exe exists mode with encription. This application is packed with this mode. And i can't just open it with 7-zip. In archive only files of packer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.